# One page site navigation flicker (Chrome)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My website navigation flickers when scrolling down.

But as soon as you press one of the links on the navigation or open inspect element the site scrolls fine...

The link for the site is [here](http://jwoods.me/) and [this](https://github.com/ijames55/jwoods.me) is the github repo for reference.

The problem seems to be the css as changing the JavaScript does not have any effect, specifically this code:

EDIT: This seems to only be a chrome issue

**CSS**

```
 nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 99;
  padding-top: 1vh;
  }


nav a {
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Arial, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 1vw;
  padding: 0 3vw 4px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') 
    || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

    var target = $(this.hash);
    target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
       if (target.length) {
         $('html,body').animate({
             scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Its not a Promotional social networking site.

Comment: It works fine on jsfiddle.... It is here though if you want it: http://jsfiddle.net/mc4sq10y/

Comment: to be honest, I can't see any flickering in the navigation when clicking or scrlling (in FF 33.1)

Comment: I see it on chrome v39 and IE11 when you scroll down using the scroll wheel before clicking anything.

Comment: seems to be a Chrome issue, no flickering in FF on Ubuntu.

Comment: Yep it's only a chrome issue